# How to get the contents from a URL which is passed as a request parameter

Tags: java, get, httprequest

I am trying to get the contents from an external URL in my GET call like

http://localhost:8080/getinfo?url=http://hello-ext.com/Serving?cn=display&c=23&pl=VAST&pli=21933633&PluID=0&pos=4729&ord=[timestamp]&cim=1

However, when I debug, I can see the URL is getting truncated to 
http://hello-ext.com/Serving?cn=display

omitting the contents after the first '&'. How can I pass the entire URL for my GET method so that I get

String URL = http://hello-ext.com/Serving?cn=display&c=23&pl=VAST&pli=21933633&PluID=0&pos=4729&ord=[timestamp]&cim=1

Comment: You should URL-encode the entire internal URL. Otherwise the parameters are considered to be part of the top URL. In fact, whenever you pass a parameter value, you should URL-encode it, as it may contain special characters, whether it is a URL or not.

Comment: Try doing a url encode like `&` can be written as %26 and space as %20 & get it & decode it

Comment: @RealSkeptic - using '@Encoded' attribute in my rest controller method ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the server side. You are supposed to do this on the *sending* side.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String url="http://hello-ext.com/Serving?cn=display&c=23&pl=VAST&pli=21933633&PluID=0&pos=4729&ord=[timestamp]&cim=1";
String encodedurl=URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8");
```

Comment: In the rest controller itself I am getting the truncated URL when I hit that method.